# dash DataTable reset on page reload

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

The following code reads a simple model (3 columns 50 rows) from a CSV file for editing in a table in my (larger) dash app. Editing a cell writes the whole table back to file as expected. However, reloading the page displays the table as it was originally loaded from file, thus losing any edits. Any clues about how to keep the edits between page reloads?

```
df_topic_list=pd.read_csv(model_file)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id='memory-output'),
    html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(df_topic_list.to_dict('records'),
            id='memory-table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_topic_list.columns],editable=True
        ),
    ])
])

@app.callback(Output('memory-output', 'data'),
              Input('memory-table', 'data'))
def on_data_set_table(data):
    pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(model_file,index=False)
    return data

app.run_server(port=8052)
```

Comment: maybe you load from one file but you save in different file - and later it load again from original file. What do you have in `model_file`? Where is code which load data?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Apologies, I missed the line that loads the file - code snippet now edited. The original file is being updated every time in the callback. The problem is the persistence of df_topic_list, which is being remembered across page reloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you refresh page then it doesn't run all code again but it only sends again `app.layout` which it generated only once and which has original data from file. And when you update data in cell in table then it updates only values in browser (using JavaScript) but not in code `app.layout`.

But it has options to presist values in browser memory and it should use these values after reloading.

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id='memory-output'),
    html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(
            df_topic_list.to_dict('records'),
            id='memory-table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_topic_list.columns],
            editable=True,

            persistence=True,           # <---
            persisted_props=["data"],   # <---

        )
    ])
])
```

It works for me but it seems some people had problem with this.
See issues: [Dash table edited data not persisting · Issue #684 · plotly/dash-table](https://github.com/plotly/dash-table/issues/684)

But I found other method to keep it.

I assign table to separated variable - ie. `table` - and in callback I replace `table.data` in this table.

```
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, callback
from dash import dcc, html, dash_table
import pandas as pd

model_file = 'data.csv'

df_topic_list = pd.read_csv(model_file)

app = Dash(__name__)

table = dash_table.DataTable(
            df_topic_list.to_dict('records'),
            id='memory-table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_topic_list.columns],
            editable=True,
        )

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id='memory-output'),
    html.Div([table])
])

@app.callback(
    Output('memory-output', 'data'),
    Input('memory-table', 'data')
)
def on_data_set_table(data):
    pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(model_file, index=False)

    table.data = data  # <--- replace data

    return data

app.run_server(port=8052)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @furas. The first solution has dash reporting that `A callback is missing Outputs` although the persistence is working on page reload. In fact the edits seem to persist even after restarting the Jupiter kernel! However, the callback is not actually writing back to the file - the code in `on_data_set_table` isn't being executed. The second solution seems to reproduce the same lack of persistence as my original code and also doesn't write the file. So, neither solutions update the file - although the first solution does provide persistence to edits on page reload.

Comment: I tested it only as local script `python script.py` (because you didn't mention that you run on `jupyter`) and It says nothing about missing `Output` which I removed from `callback` - but it works also if I keep original `Output` in code - so you can put back `Output` and `dcc.Store()`.

Comment: I added back `Output` and `dcc.Store()` and tested in Jupyter - and both versions works for me.

Comment: Hi @furas, many thanks for bearing with me and apologies for not mentioning Jupyter earlier. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks once again.